# my auto rig addon pro froze

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, add-on, bones

I been having this problem for 3 days now of my addon, the auto rig is bugging, all I want to do is animate & to move the body. However, my file works but the addon isn't.[image]

Comment: This site is about helping with the tools and addons that come with Blender. For paid third-party addons please contact the developers for support.